# Homogeneous space

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups

I want to solve this problem: A k-frame in $R_{n}$ is a k-tuple of vectors in $R_{n} (f_{1},..., f_{k})$ that are orthonormal. Let $V_{k,n}$ denote the set of all k-frames in $R_{n}$. Show that $V_{k,n}$ is a homogeneous space.

$\textbf{My attempt:}$

Orthonormality implies $f_{i}f_{j}=\delta_{ij}$.

If $V_{k,n}$ is a homogeneous space, it should be written as a coset G/H with $V_{k,n}\equiv G$. Thus, we must find an equivalence relation $g'\sim g \quad \text{iff} \quad \exists h\in H \quad \text{such that} \quad g'=gh$.

We can write $(f_{1},f_{2},...,f_{k})=f_{a}^{-1}(f_{1}f_{a}+f_{2}f_{a}+...+f_{a}f_{a}+...+f_{k}f_{a})=f_{a}^{-1}(\delta_{1a}+\delta_{2a}+...+0+...+\delta_{ka})$

Thus, the subgroup H could be a set of all tuples $H={f_{1},...,f_{k}}$ of a frame and there is an $h=f_{a}$ of H such that $g'=gh$ where $g'=(\delta_{1a}+\delta_{2a}+...+0+...+\delta_{ka})$ and $g=(f_{1},f_{2},...,f_{k})$

Does this make sense? What do you think?

Comment: To see it is homogeneous, for each pair of $k$ frames $(f_1,\ldots, f_k)$ and $(g_1,\ldots, g_k)$, there is a homeomorphism $h$ of $V_{n,k}$ such that $h(f_1,\ldots,f_k)=(g_1,\ldots,g_k)$. Now remember your linear algebra...

Comment: $R_n$ is just $\Bbb R^n$ I suppose?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry for that. But what should h be so I can have this relation?

Comment: Think about matrices that are used in base changes in linear algebra.